# .NET: How to handle a json response of unknown structure

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying out the Facebook Messenger send api. From my testing, there are two responses so far.  For response 200, it is something like:

```
{
    "recipient_id": "1730337993881234",
    "message_id": "mid.1464765699033:1edf6d866bc6de1234"
}
```

For a 400 response, it is something like:

```
{
   "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Invalid fbid.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "EjUIvT0HLph"
            }
}
```

I can create two classes to match these two responses. My testing is however not exhaustive. Is there a way to handle a json response of unknown structure in .NET, short of treating it as a plain string?

Comment: Have you tried something in the direction of using `dynamic`?

Comment: how are you trying to handle it at the moment?

Comment: @SimonPrice I am creating two classes to match those two structures.

Comment: @OldGeezer Just checked out the Messenger API and there is a known number of responses, check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the responses you've listed you could map this using one class.  Simply make sure there are properties for recipient_id, message_id and also an error property.

This way when you receive a response if it was an error your error property would be populated, which you can test for, and if not then the other properties would get populated leaving error null.

I think this might be the simplest way and avoids having to deal with creating custom model binders for dynamic objects, especially when the structure of responses is known!

**Edit**

I've just checked out the messenger api and it does indeed only return two types of [responses](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#response) so my suggestion should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not a good idea to mix apple and oranges like Mo09890 suggests. A better idea is to parse result differently. E.g. in your case of an error you should get an indication that there was an error and then you can parse to a special error structure using JSON.NET.

I use RestSharp and for each response that I get I check if it's an error or not like that:

```
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    MyError result = JObject.Parse(response.Content) 
                            .ToObject<MyError>();

    if (result.ErrorCode != null)
    {
        return result;
    }

    throw new ApplicationException($"Service error. StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}. Details: {response.Content}");
}
```

Otherwise if you completely don't know the structure there is no way you can create one in .NET. So you will either have to work with the result as a generic JSON object that you can parse using JSON.NET e.g. or any other library or if your client supports it: dynamic keyword:

```
JObject myObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
```